# $\frac{\sin x}{x^5} - \frac{1}{x^4} \underset{x\to 0}{\approx} \frac{-1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$, right?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I was reading an set of notes about Taylor series, and I came across a part I think is a typo. I want to make sure, because I want to understand this stuff correctly. Here is the relevant page of the article. You can see where I've indicated the typo in the margin.

[image]

In the space I've marked, do you think it should say $\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{-1}{6}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right :

$$\frac{\sin x}{x^5}-\frac{1}{x^4}=\frac{\sin x-x}{x^5}\sim_0 \frac{-1/6 x^3}{x^5}=\frac{-1}{6x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Well done, Sami!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right — it should be $\frac{-1}{6x^2}$.

PS: just to ease your mind in the future, note that you always can check such results, when you have a doubt, with Mathematica or [WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/18weA61).